# Is there a way to require signing from 2 people before uploading a file to sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I was trying to find out a way to require the signature (or some kind of authorization) before being able to upload a file to sharepoint.

Let me explain the flow:

You have access to upload files into a sharepoint list or page:

1. You select the file to be uploaded
2. Depending on the sharepoint list, let's say it's for Team N°1, some kind of ticket/mail is opened or sent to the Team N°1 approvers, and these 2 people need to approve before the file is populated on the list.
3. Once both approved, the file is shown on the sharepoint list.

I ask this here as I wanted to know if there already exists something like this out there or as a built-in sharepoint feature, or if I needed to code it and where.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing like that exists. However here is a possible scenario:

1. Add two columns to your document library, like "First Approval" (with "yes/no") and "Second Approval" (with "yes/no")
2. Create a view for your document library that only shows the documents WHEN "First Approval" and "Second Approval" equal to "yes"
3. Let the user uploads the file, and trigger a workflow that sends an email to the two teams when a new file has been uploaded
4. The persons in charge go to edit the item and set the "First Approval" or "Second Approval" to "yes" (or if it's not approved you can use a workflow to delete the item if "No" is selected)
5. Then when both have approved, the file will automatically appear in the document library view

I hope it helps.